# Representing a Tesseract as an intersection of Halfspaces

Tags: geometry

In 2D, you can represent a square as an intersection of 4 halfspaces defined by hyperplanes:

1. point: $[1; 0]$; normal: $[1; 0]$
2. point: $[-1; 0]$; normal: $[-1; 0]$
3. point: $[0; 1]$; normal: $[0; 1]$
4. point: $[0; -1]$; normal: $[0; -1]$

This creates a square with points at $[1; 1]$, $[1; -1]$, $[-1; 1]$ and $[-1; -1]$.
Similarly, in 3D, you can represent a cube as an intersection of 6 halfspaces defined by hyperplanes:

1. point: $[1; 0; 0]$; normal: $[1; 0; 0]$
2. point: $[-1; 0; 0]$; normal: $[-1; 0; 0]$
3. point: $[0; 1; 0]$; normal: $[0; 1; 0]$
4. point: $[0; -1; 0]$; normal: $[0; -1; 0]$
5. point: $[0; 0; \mathbf{1}]$; normal: $[0; 0; \mathbf{1}]$
6. point: $[0; 0; \mathbf{-1}]$; normal: $[0; 0; \mathbf{-1}]$

Does this logic extend to the fourth dimension, so you could represent a tesseract with 8 halfspaces?

Comment: Absolutely. In $d$ dimensions, $2d$ halfplanes perpendicuar to the $d$ coordinate axis. Even in $1$ dimension, an interval if formed by the intersection of two half-lines.

Comment: By definition, the cube in $n$-dimensional Cartesian space $\mathbb{R}^n$ is the Cartesian product $[-1,+1]^n$, which is an intersection of $2n$ half-spaces just as you describe. And, also by definition, the tesseract is the cube in $\mathbb{R}^4$, namely $[-1,+1]^4$. So yes, the tesseract can be described just as you say.

Comment: Great, thanks for the responses. I'll mark it as an accepted answer, if you write it as one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, the logic extends.

A hypercube of arbitrary dimension $n$ centered around the origin is defined by $n$ pairs of planes $-1\le x_i\le 1$ where $x_i$ is the $i$-th coordinate of the point to be plugged into these equations. So the $-1\le x_1$ corresponds to your point $[-1,0,…]$ and normal $[-1,0,…]$, the $x_1\le1$ is what you describe as point $[1,0,…]$ and normal $[1,0,…]$ and so on.

Another common definition takes $0$ instead of $-1$ as the lower bound, so it has one corner at the origin. But that's just a cosmetic difference.